# Mostrar una cadena json en una jsp con content-type aplicación/json

Tags: jsp

Tengo una jsp que pueden ocurrir dos casos:
En el primero si una variable x es vacía o N se lanza una URL.
En el segundo si una variable x es S la URL que se lanzaría en el primer caso debe devolverse en formato json y para eso el content-type debe ser igual a application/json.

**El problema es el siguiente :**

Al poner el content-type a json mediante `<%@page contentType=''application/json''%>`

Me produce el siguiente error de sintaxis.

> SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected character at línea 1 column 1 if te
>   JSON data.

En el body simplemente tengo el json en formato texto que quiero mostrar:

```
{''response'':{''checkfreeSSOURL'':x}}
```

No sé que estoy haciendo mal ,podéis ayudarme por favor.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Como sugerencia puedo decirte que deberias separar el codigo Java del HTML/JSP. Eso que usas se llama scriptlet y no es recomendado.

Comment: No es un scriptlet, está generando un JSON con JSP, del mismo modo que se podría generar HTML o XML

Answer (score 1):

El formato JSON requiere el uso de comillas dobles, pero una comilla doble (`"`) **no** es lo mismo que dos comillas simples (`''`), que es lo que tienes:

```
{''response'':{''checkfreeSSOURL'': ...}}
```

Debería ser:

```
{"response":{"checkfreeSSOURL": ...}}
```

Answer (score 0):

aunque en el código que he puesto aquí este todo con comillas simples en realidad en mi código está con comillas dobles.

Gracias por tu respuesta.